# xlDialogSaveAs - End ALL code if "cancel" is selected

Tags: vba, excel

EDIT: I figured it out myself. I feel pretty silly, but replacing "Exit Sub" with "End" works perfectly.

Background: I have a Sub that uses the "Call" function to run multiple subs within one Sub (see Code #1 below).

```
Option Explicit

Sub MIUL_Run_All()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As String

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer

Call OptimizeCode_Begin

Call Format_MIUL
Call Custom_Sort_MIUL
Call Insert_Process_List
Call Format_Process_List

Call OptimizeCode_End

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  SecondsElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "ss")

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

My first code that is called out, "Format_MIUL", prompts the user to save the file, using the following line of code (see Code #2 below). This code works, but the problem is that if the user presses the "Cancel" button, the rest of the code called out in the main sub (Code #1 above) will continue to run. I want ALL code to stop if the user presses the cancel button. I just can't seem to figure out how to do that.

```
'Save file as .xlsm
MsgBox "       Save as Excel Workbook (.xlsx)!"
Dim userResponse As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
userResponse = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(, 51)
On Error GoTo 0
If userResponse = False Then
Exit Sub
Else
End If
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I feel pretty silly, but replacing "Exit Sub" with "End" works perfect.

Comment: Please write an answer for you question so others can find a solution to similar issues

Comment: Neater is to convert Format_MIUL to a function which returns TRUE when saved ans False when not so you can call it like so: 
If Format_Miu Then
'Other calls
End If

Comment: @jkpieterse gah, saw that comment just now

Answer (score 2):

The `Call` keyword has been obsolete for 20 years, you can remove it.

The `End` keyword will effectively *end* execution, but it's pretty much a big red "self-destruct" button that you effectively never need to use, given properly structured code.

Looks like `Format_MIUL` is a `Sub` procedure. Make it a `Function` and *return* a `Boolean` value that tells the caller whether it's ok to proceed, or if the rest of the operations should be cancelled:

```
Private Function Format_MUIL() As Boolean
    '...
    'Save file as .xlsm
    MsgBox "       Save as Excel Workbook (.xlsx)!"
    Dim userResponse As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    userResponse = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(, 51)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'return False if userResponse isn't a filename, True otherwise:
    Format_MUIL = Not VarType(userResponse) = vbBoolean
End Function
```

And now instead of this:

> ```
> Call Format_MIUL
> ```

The caller can do this:

```
If Not Format_MIUL Then Exit Sub
```

And there you go, graceful exit without any self-destruct buttons pressed.

Comment: Interesting...I don't do much VBA, this code isn't really needed just a nice tool for other users here, so my knowledge of properly structured code is quite limited. It isn't exactly clear to me how I would replace all my "Call" keywords with Functions though. Not every Sub has a dialog like this one. Also, where would I put the "Format MIUL = Not VarType... within my Format MIUL code?

Comment: I didn't say "replace the `Call` keywords with functions", I said *remove the `Call` keywords* - they're redundant. `Call DoSomething` is exactly the same as just `DoSomething`. And yes, `Format_MIUL = ...` goes in the `Format_MIUL` **function** - that's how you set a function's return value in VBA, by assigning to its identifier.

Comment: alright, but am I leaving my original code                       
`'Save file as .xlsm
MsgBox "       Save as Excel Workbook (.xlsx)!"
Dim userResponse As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
userResponse = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(, 51)
On Error GoTo 0
If userResponse = False Then
Exit Sub
Else
End If`                                                                                                   
and just adding `Format_MUIL = Not VarType(userResponse) = vbBoolean` to the end of that? Regardless, I will check out Rubberduck that sounds great.

Comment: @CC268 I've edited to clarify, hope it helps. The `Format_MUIL = Not VarType(userResponse) = vbBoolean` part actually replaces the whole `If userResponse = False` block.

Comment: great, thanks! And I can do this for all the other Subs I "Call"? Even if I don't do any xlDialogSaveAs in the other ones? For the most part they are just Subs that do general formatting, etc.

Comment: Hmm...I get a Variable not defined error on my main Sub that calls the `If Not Format_MIUL Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Is your function not called `Format_MIUL`?

Comment: yes it was called Format_MIUL. I did exactly as you posted above. Don't worry about it though. I appreciate the help and think I will go with what I figured out, even though it isn't best practice. Maybe I will experiment with the Functions if I have some more time to later.